# ExtJs - Get element by div class?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

How do I get the **ExtJs component object** of a Div by class name?

Say my div is:

```
<div class="abc"></div>
```

How do I get the ExtJs object of this Div to perform e.g. `getWidth()`

Note: There is no `id` given.

**What I tried:**

```
Ext.select(".abc")
Ext.query(".abc")
```

---

**Edit:**

Error:
`Object  has no method 'getWidth'`

```
<div id="main">
<div class="abc"></div>
</div>
```

```
  var d = Ext.get( "main" );
  d.query('.abc').getWidth();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use

```
var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.abc');
var el = Ext.get(dom[0]);
```

This will return an `Ext.Element`. You can then use ext methods on el like so

```
el.on('click', function(){}, scope);
```

or

```
el.getWidth()
```

Comment: Does not work. Note that it is `class` not `id`. Returns null.

Comment: As far as I know Ext.get() requires a id

Comment: Tried it before, says: `Cannot read property 'Query' of undefined `

Comment: use `Ext.dom.Query`. Also, we don't need to create a new `Ext.Element`, we can directly pass the dom object to `Ext.get` to get an `Ext.Element`. Answer edited to reflect the same.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you mean [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) (not ExtJs component object). If yes try this code

```
var d = Ext.get( "main" );
alert(d.down('.abc').getWidth());​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/UYv6Z/)

Comment: Great +1! I didn't recognized that Ext.Element hast up/down too!

Comment: Yes. Check my answer. Either ways, if you're gonna assign an id to an element, you can directly do it to the element you're trying to retrieve in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, I just checked your edit! Works perfectly! Edit: I cant edit the div and add an id so I need to go by class.

Answer (score 6):

For Ext4 and up you could use the following:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[cls=myCls]');
```

And you will get and array of this components

source: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Answer (score 4):

```
Ext.select('abc');
```

This method works in EXT 4 also.

In your example, just remove the dot when calling the string of the class name.